# Как отследить сколько раз использовалась команда в discord?

Tags: discord, discord.py

подскажите пожалуйста, хочу сделать в команде получения ежедневной награды счётчик использования этой самой команды (так называемый **streak bonus**), но не могу понять алгоритма как это реализовать.
Если кто то уже такое делал, подскажите пожалуйста
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, это может быть реализовано через базу данных.Например через `MongoDb` или же `Sqlite3`. Может быть, даже через файл json, но я не уверен в этом.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).